# pymssql "InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason."

Tags: python, pymssql

I can login to database in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) with the following:

[image: sql server windows]

However, in Python I tried

```
pymssql.connect(host='.\SQLSERVER', user='sa', password='1234', database='HastaneArsiv')
```

but I got the error message:

> pymssql.InterfaceError: Connection to the database failed for an unknown reason.

In the SQL Server Configuration Manager i have verified that TCP/IP is enabled.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Check if the "SQL Server Browser" service is running. That is required for pymssql to connect using `host=servername\instance` or `server=servername\instance`. Also note that the screenshot for the SSMS connection does *not* specify an instance name, so using `.\SQLSERVER` may not work for you in any case if you are really trying to connect to the (unnamed) default instance `(local)`.

Comment: Thank u for your help

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way can be solve this problem but nothing worked for me.I solved this problem install the Sql Server 2008R2 Service Pack 3 .